# Ubuntu won't recognize updated version of Python with pyenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyenv

I am trying to update from Python 2.7.17 to 3.8.1 so that I can run `pip install pandas`. I have installed pyenv, followed the instructions to add pyenv to my path, and installed 3.8.1. But every time I run python, it will not use version 3.8.1.

Running `pyenv version` returns 3.8.1, running `python -V` returns 2.7.17. Similarly, running `python` runs 2.7.17, and when I type `python3` it runs Python 3.7.6?! But if I run `pyenv global 3.7.6` the terminal tells me that 3.7.6 isn't installed!

I have also run `pyenv global 3.8.1` in attempt to switch from 2.7.17 so 3.8.1, but still defaults to 2.7.17 when I type `python`.

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10, if that helps.
Any help is greatly appreciated -- I am very very confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The python 3.7.6 error is because you have not installed it with pyenv. You should run ```ls ~/.pyenv/versions/``` to verify the avaible installed versions that you could use with pyenv and ```pyenv install --list | grep " 3\.[6789]"``` to see all the avaible python 3.6+ versions that you can install with pyenv.

Comment: Also, after you run ```pyenv global 3.8.1``` you can verify that Python version you just installed is working with  ```python -m test```.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

`pyenv shell 3.8.1`

to set the PYENV_VERSION environment variable to the desired 3.8.1 version. But, I recommend you to use a virtual env:

`pyenv virtualenv 3.8.1 my_test_env`

and the activate it with:

`pyenv activate my_test_env`

For more info, this [guide](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) is super useful.